# Android: If Map contains Value, Change Button Resource Not Working

Tags: java, android, dictionary, android-viewpager

I have a favourites button and I want it to change it's image depending on whether an ID is found in a favourites map, however it doesn't seem to be working.
Here is my code:

```
boolean containsShop = false;
             for (Map<String, String> hashMap : TabsViewPagerFragmentActivity.favouritesData)
                {

                    containsShop = hashMap.containsValue(shopID);



                }

             if(containsShop) {
                 isFavourite = true;
                 favouritesBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.is_a_favourite);
             }  else {

                 isFavourite = false;
                 favouritesBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.favourite_normal);
             }
```

It seems to set the button to `R.drawable.favourite_normal` even if the ID is in the map.
What am I doing wrong?

Edit:

Sorry I copied the wrong code. - I just noticed that it only seems to set the Button to 
`R.drawable.is_a_favourite` if the object was the last object added to the favouritesData ArrayList

Answer (score 0, accepted):

and add a `break` statement in the `for loop`, if you found the value. Otherwise in next iteration of your loop, the `boolean` value may be overwritten.

```
containsShop= hashMap.containsValue(shopID);
if (containsShop) break;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
containsShop = hashMap.containsValue(shopID);
```

replace this

```
containsVenue = hashMap.containsValue(shopID);
^^^^^^^^^^^^
```